# How consume WCF service in REST mode?

Tags: .net, rest, wcf

Deployed wcf service (.net 4.0). Service side config looks like:

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" 
          bindingNamespace="https://mydomain/myservice/services"     
          behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
          contract="MyService" />

<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="WebBehavior">
    <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Trying consume service in web app, `web.config` looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>      
        <endpoint name="MyServiceEndpointBasicHttp" 
                  address="http://myDomain/myService"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" 
                  contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" />
     </client>
     <behaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
             <behavior name="webBehavior">
                 <webHttp />       
             </behavior>     
          </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm getting exception when calling service:

> Operation 'Method1' of contract
>   'IMyService' specifies multiple
>   request body parameters to be
>   serialized without any wrapper
>   elements. At most one body parameter
>   can be serialized without wrapper
>   elements. Either remove the extra body
>   parameters or set the BodyStyle
>   property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to
>   Wrapped.

After some googling, we've set `[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]` on methods, but no success...

One interesting thing: There is always the same method name in exception, even I'm calling other methods...

Service works fine in REST mode while testing with browser by entering method name and necessary paramaters...

Comment: Can you show us the **service contract** with the definition of your service methods?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're facing similar issue as in this thread: [WCF Service Proxy throws exception when more than one parameter is used in [OperationContract] method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346554/wcf-service-proxy-throws-exception-when-more-than-one-parameter-is-used-in-opera/4347005#4347005)

"It seems you have created Proxy code using Add Service Reference dialog in VS. VS ASR dialog doesn't support WCF REST fully, so, the proxy code is missing [WebInvoke] attribute. Can you try adding [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] attribute on operations in client proxy?"

Comment: What do you mean by "adding attribute on operations in client proxy" ? In which file it has to be added?