# Why cant I use two arguments in a WCF REST POST method?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "GetCategoriesGET/{userIdArg}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    List<Video> GetVideosGET(string userIdArg);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "evals")]
    [OperationContract]
    void SubmitVideoPOST(Video videoArg, string userId);
```

And I have the implementing methods:

```
public List<Video> GetVideosGET(string userIdArg)
{

  List<Video> catsToReturn = new List<Video>();

  if (Int32.Parse(userIdArg) == 1)
  {
      catsToReturn = catsForUser1;
  }
  else if (Int32.Parse(userIdArg) == 2)
  {
      catsToReturn = catsForUser2;
  }

  return catsToReturn;

  }


  public void SubmitVideoPOST(Video videoArg, string userId)
  {

  }
```

When I browse to:

```
http://localhost:52587/Api/Content/VLSContentService.svc/GetCategoriesGET/1
```

Im getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Operation 'SubmitVideoPOST' of
>   contract 'IVLSContentService'
>   specifies multiple request body
>   parameters to be serialized without
>   any wrapper elements. At most one body
>   parameter can be serialized without
>   wrapper elements. Either remove the
>   extra body parameters or set the
>   BodyStyle property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to
>   Wrapped.

I only started getting this error on the Get request when I added the new method for POST (which I havent tried to access), what does this mean? Cant I use more than one argument?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/00c93f9f-f1f3-4f08-9927-db0e4ed91d2d) where the poster asks the same question.

The relevant part is:

```
WCF doesn't support more than one parameter with bare body, 
if you need pass several parameters in one post method operation, 
then we need set the BodyStyle to Wrapped.
```

So in your case you'd have to change your operation contract to the following:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "evals", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
void SubmitVideoPOST(Video videoArg, string userId);
```

Comment: cheers yeah sorry should have looked closer just totally confused with the whole thing but got it now thanks!

Comment: I did the same, but it was not working. I removed the BodyStyle then it worked

Answer (score 6):

The XML will not have a single root node with two parameters which would make it non-wellformed. To introduce a single root node to have to do as the error says, "wrap" it. This makes the method expect a wrapper element around the two pieces of data

Add BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped to the WebInvoke attribute

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped like the error suggested, like this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "evals", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[OperationContract]
void SubmitVideoPOST(Video videoArg, string userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat new to WCF REST myself, just did my first service last week. But I had similar issues. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540042/how-consume-wcf-service-in-rest-mode) started me in the right direction. The wrapper was my problem.