# WCF strange behaviour

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, wcf-client, wcf-rest

I got this when I consume a webservice:

> Operation 'Login' of contract 'IServices' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

I use interface look like :

```
namespace DreamServices
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,

        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,

        UriTemplate = "LogIn/{username}/{password}")]
        string Login(string username, string password);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "WaletTotalAmount/{userid}")]
        double? WaletTotalAmount(string userid);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "UserService/{userid}")]
        IList<UserServiceses> UserService(string userid);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "InsertUpdateWallet/{userid}/{Amount}/{ComissionAmount}")]
        void InsertUpdateWallet(string userid, string Amount, string ComissionAmount);

    }
}
```

and I host it then I add web reference to my site and modify the web.config such that the   will be like

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultRest">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1381/PMAHost/Service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference.IServices" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
    </client>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Please show the signatures of the methods these attributes decorate.

Comment: ok public string login(string userid) ;

Comment: public void InsertUpdateWallet(string userid, string amount)

Comment: post your complete WCF Interface code.

Comment: see my modified question

Answer (score 0):

First I'm not sure why you are using GET operation for login, you should use POST right? Next you have defined two parameters in the `UriTemplate` but the method contain only one. I would suggest you to use a class as parameter and instead of returning string you could return a model as well.

```
public class LoginModel
{
   public string username { get; set; }
   public string password { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
   public bool success { get; set; }
   public string error { get; set; }
}

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/LogIn")]
public Result login(LoginModel loginModel)
```

Comment: but I used this web service in android and worked very well , do u know in asp.net how to add this attributes to client proxy AS in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346554/wcf-service-proxy-throws-exception-when-more-than-one-parameter-is-used-in-oper