# where the client proxy be saved

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I add web reference to WCF service

I want to modify the proxy file be automatically generated by the web service reference tool

I want to add before each method atttribute like

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,

BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,

UriTemplate = "LogIn/{username}/{password}")]
```

any idea how to do that

Best regards

Comment: i think the settings are added in the web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi there:**

I'm adding this since the post above didn't really made it clear how to add WebInvoke attributes in client proxy code so I'm making this available to clear any confusion as to how its done.

#### STEP 1

Go To your VS Project Folder and Locate your "Service References" Folder. Find the Reference folder you are using, if you used default one when adding the Service then should be something like "ServiceReference1".

Inside that folder theres a Reference.cs file, thats the one you need in order to update your methods.

So for example lets say you created a REST Service and your WebInvoke attributes were left out. You can just add them there.

#### STEP 2

Just find the line that starts with "[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute":

Should look something like this

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/YourMethodName", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/YourMethodNameResponse")]
```

#### STEP 3

Now after that line you want to add your WebInvoke code like this:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/YourMethodName", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/YourMethodNameResponse")]

[System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/YourMethodName")]
```

Thats all theres to it.

**NOTE:** If by any chance you delete your WCF service reference the changes you made will be gone. So make sure you backup the file after you are done making changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update answer:**
It seems you have created Proxy code using Add Service Reference dialog in VS. VS ASR dialog doesn't support WCF REST fully, so, the proxy code is missing [WebInvoke] attribute. Can you try adding `[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]` attribute on operations in client proxy?
Source:
[WCF Service Proxy throws exception when more than one parameter is used in [OperationContract] method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346554/wcf-service-proxy-throws-exception-when-more-than-one-parameter-is-used-in-oper)

If I understand your question clearly.
If you want to add WebInvoke attribute before each method, Go to your WCF Serivce Interface Class like ( IService.cs ). May be it is placed in your App_Code Folder.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{ 
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate = "LogIn/{username}/{password}")]
void DoWork();

}
```

If you want to make changes to your proxy class setting then go to your web config under the system.ServiceModel tag.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:56662/WebSite2/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: see my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466537/wcf-strange-behaviour

Comment: @AMH Check my updated answer, Sure it will work, and remember to mark it as your answer.

Comment: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:1381/PMAHost/Service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: my endpoint look liek       <endpoint address="http://localhost:1381/PMAHost/Service.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
          contract="ServiceReference.IServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />

Comment: I still cannot consume it from my website

Comment: visit this link the user have the same problem as you have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346554/wcf-service-proxy-throws-exception-when-more-than-one-parameter-is-used-in-oper

Comment: oh my god, this was my question, the answer was the proxy code is missing [WebInvoke] attribute. Can you try adding [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] attribute on operations in client , where iin my asp.net page can find the proxy

Comment: add the following attribute `[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] ` in your all methods in your Interface Class( in the appcode folder )

Comment: what're u taking about the WCF in different project with the attributes u mentioned, I hosted it then in another asp.net web project I add web reference , so It create away to call functions that raise error . do u know where the proxy file , or what ever in this asp.net site to modify

Comment: you are calling WCF service from client side ( javascript ) or code behind ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13878/discussion-between-waqar-janjua-and-amh)