# InvalidOperationException when calling a WCF RESTful service method with multiple arguments?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I have the following code for a service called `AuthenticationService`:

**IAuthenticationService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool Login(string username, string password, string applicationName);
}
```

**AuthenticationService.svc.cs**

```
public sealed class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public bool Login(string username, string password, string applicationName)
    {
        // TODO: add the logic to authenticate the user

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- START: to return JSON -->
    <services>
        <service name="ImageReviewPoc.Service.AuthenticationService">
            <endpoint contract="ImageReviewPoc.Service.Contracts.IAuthenticationService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <!-- END: to return JSON -->
    <behaviors>
        <!-- START: to return JSON -->
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <!-- END: to return JSON -->
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and I have the following console application that consumes the service:

**Program.cs**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Login().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task Login()
    {
        var client = new AuthenticationServiceClient();
        var ok = await client.LoginAsync("User", "Password!", "Console Application");
        client.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(ok);
    }
}
```

**App.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:62085/AuthenticationService.svc/"
         binding="webHttpBinding"
         contract="AuthenticationServiceReference.IAuthenticationService"
         kind="webHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I used [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) to test the service sending the following JSON data and it worked:

```
{"username": "reviewer", "password": "456", "applicationName": "123"}
```

However, when I tested the service using the console application I got an

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation 'Login' of contract 'IAuthenticationService' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

As you can see from `IAuthenticationService.cs` code, I already set `BodyStyle` to `Wrapped`. Can someone guide me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Note the following:

- I already search Stackoverflow and the internet for a solution. Almost all the solutions are about setting `BodyStyle`. It may have helped others but didn't do much to me.
- I tried both `Login` and `LoginAsync`; it's the same result
- I referenced the service by adding it through "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate edition, if you care to know)
- I know I can call the service using other ways; e.g., HttpClient, but what I want to know is why the auto-generated client doesn't work

Comment: Did you already update your service reference on the client-side after the change to `BodyStyle`?

Comment: i think, the json request that is going in is not proper. can you check with fiddler and see what is the request going like. may be the request is not well formed...

Comment: @khlr, yes, I changed the service and updated the reference at least 739,000 times :)

Comment: @Saravanan, I'll check and see. I'm not sure it even reaches the server. The exception is thrown in the client (the console application) when it tries to call the method.

Comment: @Saravanan, as I suspected, it doesn't even reach the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should call your service.

```
    public void DoLogin()
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:62085/AuthenticationService.svc/Login";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/json";

        string data = "{\"username\": \"reviewer\", \"password\": \"456\", \"applicationName\": \"123\"}";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Send the data.
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(x))
        {
            using(var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using(var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    //Here you will get response
                    string loginResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why "should"? Why can't I just use the auto-generated client? I know I can call the service successfully from Postman, Fiddler, `HttpWebRequest`, `HttpClient`, and thousands other ways. What I'm asking about is "Why it isn't working" not "How  else I can consume it". Anyway, I updated the notes at the end to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not call REST service using auto generated client.

Comment: Is this based on experience or an officially documented limitation? If the latter, can you please guide me to the source?

Comment: Unlike SOAP endpoints (like BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding, etc) which have a way to expose metadata about itself (WSDL or Mex) with information about all the operations / parameters in the endpoint, there's currently no standard way to expose metadata for a non-SOAP endpoint like webHttpBinding-based endpoints. Hence auto generated proxy class is not useful for calling REST service.

Answer (score 0):

Add to Login/LoginAsync  **Client Contract Methods**

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)].
```

So your client contract will look like:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.IAuthenticationService")]
public interface IAuthenticationService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/Login", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/LoginResponse")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool Login(string username, string password, string applicationName);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/Login", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/LoginResponse")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> LoginAsync(string username, string password, string applicationName);
}
```

Client contract is generated automatically. So you should do this each time after service reference is updated.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477923/where-the-client-proxy-be-saved)

Comment: You're saying that I need to modify the auto-generated proxy? Why? Is it a known issue/limitation? Can you guide to an official (or other reliable) source that document this?

Comment: I can't find any official information about Restful WCF Proxy. You could read this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. This is a workaround that is useful in case one is desperate to use the auto-generated (I'm not). I guess I'm convinced now that this is a limitation.